# How can I avoid boxing when pass a struct value as an interface value?

Tags: c#

Interface (I) is a reference type, struct (S) is a value type. Structs can implement interfaces.

```
public interface I {}
struct S: I {}
```

Assume there is a value of S which is passed to a method as an argument of I. In this case it has to be boxed.

```
void Method(I i) {}

void Test() {
   var s = new S();
   this.Method(s); // <---- boxing!
}
```

Is there a way to avoid boxing in this case?

Comment: sounds like a potential interview question to... i'll try to remember that one

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can avoid boxing if you change the definition of `Method` to:

```
void Method<T>(T i) where T : I
{
}
```

This avoids boxing, because at runtime the CLR specialises generic methods based on the type of the generic argument(s). Reference types can all share the same implementation, while struct types each get their own version. This means all the operations in `Method` which depend on `T` will take into account the size of the concrete struct type.

You must be careful however, since calling virtual methods defined on `System.Object` like `Equals` or `GetHashCode` will cause `i` to be boxed since virtual method dispatch requires a method table pointer (although the JIT may be able to do the dispatch statically in some cases). However, if your struct type overrides the virtual method(s) in question, then boxing will not need to be done, since the method to call is again known statically since structs (and hence their members) are sealed.

Usually you can avoid calling `Equals` or `GetHashCode` directly by constraining `T` further to implement `IEquatable<T>` and using an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for comparisons e.g.

```
void Method<T>(T i) where T : I, IEquatable<T>
{
    T other = ...
    if(i.Equals(other))    //avoids boxing
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget the struct constraint? where T : struct, I

Comment: @BradRem: If you know your type at compile time when you pass it in, C# type inference will kick in and it will be like calling `Method<S>(s);`. At this point it's recognized you're using a struct and will avoid boxing. EDIT: However, if you don't know the type of `s` at compile time (i.e., you have it typed only as interface `I` say by writing: `I s = new S()`) then it will still be boxed. (of course, at that point it's _already_ boxed so not really much do do)

Comment: OK, I see: instead of `Method` accepting type `I`, we are using generics to make `Method` accept the actual struct type. Throwing on the constraint then limits us to only objects of type `I`.

Comment: Your statement that boxing will occur on calls to Equals and GetHashCode is only partially correct. It will occur on those calls **if the struct does not override those methods**. If the methods are overridden then the compiler generates code that calls the methods directly rather than going through the vtable.

Comment: @EricLippert - Thanks for the correction. Does that still apply if the base implementation is called from the overridden method? Since `ValueType` is a reference type, does boxing need to happen so `this` is a reference instead of the struct itself?

Comment: @Lee: The base implementation is expecting a `this` of type `object`, so yes, it has to box. Also, `GetType` cannot be overridden because it is not virtual, so the receiver always gets boxed -- but then again, why are you calling `GetType` on an unboxed struct? You already know its type!

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
public interface I {}
public struct S : I {}
public class Foo
{
    public static void Bar<T>(T i)
        where T : I
    {}
}
```