# Boxing when casting struct to parent interface but not when using the as keyword

Tags: c#

Rider tells me there's boxing when passing a variable of type structA that implements interfaceA to a method expecting a parameter of type interfaceA.
If I add `as interfaceA` Rider no longer warns me about the boxing, but states the cast is redundant and suggest to remove it.

I rather have redundant cast than boxing here. But I'm not sure if using `as` here has any impact on the boxing when casting?

Example:

```
public interface IA{}

public struct SA: IA{}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void Foo(IA param) { }

    public void Bar()
    {
        SA myStruct = new SA();
        Foo(myStruct); // Boxing warning
        Foo(myStruct as IA); // No boxing warning, redundant cast suggestion.
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of what I see in Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F959I.png)

Comment: There is no way to avoid boxing here. A struct implementing an interface has to be boxed to be viewed as an instance of that interface, and the `as` also does this (in fact it yields the exact same code). In select scenarios, the JIT compiler is able to see through this and avoid the boxing at runtime, but if you truly want no boxing at all ever (which isn't the end of the world, despite what your IDE might say) then don't access structs through interfaces.

Comment: You don't get a boxing warning for the second one because *you've written code that is explicitly boxing*, so you already know about it.

Comment: Contrary to what @JeroenMostert says, to avoid boxing, there is only one way. Use generics `public void Foo<T>(T param) where T : IA { }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid boxing when pass a struct value as an interface value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639886/how-can-i-avoid-boxing-when-pass-a-struct-value-as-an-interface-value)

Comment: @Charlieface: this is one of the select scenarios I was talking about, and with "no way to avoid it here" I meant "holding everything that isn't `Bar` constant". If you are free to rewrite `Foo` there are options, although one must still be careful that certain operations on the argument can still involve boxing, because from a language point of view boxing conversions are still occurring (even if some don't involve runtime boxing).

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think your answer best fit what I was looking for!
Charlieface Thanks for your suggestion! I'll see if that's achievable (The base code is very old).